# Bash Alt+Arrow keyboard combination not working in Terminal under Mojave

Tags: terminal, keyboard

I just migrated to Mojave from El Capitan. I am a extensive user of **Terminal application**.

But I got a bad surprise in this application: the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>  and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> that move cursor from one word to another **do not work anymore**.

**Expected behaviour (what should happen)**

Previously, using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> in this state (cursor is symbolised with `|`) :

`one two three four|`

Led to :

`one two three |four`

This works fine in Safari or other applications.

**Example (what actually happens)**

Using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> in this state :

`one two three four|`

Led to (in Terminal):

`one two three fou|r`

**Terminal configuration**

My terminal configuration did not change since Mojave installation (option key is *not* used as **Meta** key)

**Question**

Does anyone have a clue about what to change in my configuration and restore expected behaviour ?

Comment: I did a fresh install of Mojave and it is the expected behavior as you described it. Not sure what messed up your config. Anyway, is there a reason for not using `alt` as metakey, then moving with `Alt` + `f` and `Alt` + `b`? As for myself, i remaped `Caps` for `Esc` and use vi-mode, jumping with `w` and `b`.

Comment: I don't understand because it is the default behaviour since I use Terminal under Lion. As I use a french keyboard, I need `alt` not to be as metakey (to produce `{` `}` `[` `]` e.g.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check:

Go to Terminal > Preferences... > Profiles > Keyboard

From this pannel, check those two lines:

Key = <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> Action = `\033b`

Key = <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> Action = `\033f`

[image]

They might have gone away so you may create them again, or edit and double check the key, the modifier, and the action associated:

[image]

---

As a workaround, (actually it could even be better, so that you don't need to reach for the arrow keys), you could use <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> (jump forward) and <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (jump backward).

And because the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is far to reach, for more convenience, map the <kbd>Caps</kbd> key to <kbd>Esc</kbd> key with [Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

So that you can jump back and forth with <kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.

Comment: Actually, it was already configured as this in my profiles. But it seems that a bug prevented Terminal to take it into account. Closing all tabs, exiting app and re-running it solved the bug. Thanks for the lead !